# Order of Laravel 4 Eloquent Model Observer Events

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

According to http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers the following events are being fired when creating a new item. *creating* then *created* then *saving* then *saved*.

However when I do call a model class, the events are being fired the other way round. Saving is called before creating.

**My Code:**

```
class TBone extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'bone';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $guarded = array('id');

}
```

**The Observer Class:**

```
class ObserverLeBone{

    public function creating($bone)
    {
        echo "creating\r\n";
    }

    public function saving($bone) 
    {
        echo "saving\r\n";
    }

    public function updating($bone) 
    {
        echo "updating\r\n";
    }
}
```

**The Test:**

```
class EloquentTest extends TestCase {

    public function testObserver()
    {
       TBone::observe(new ObserverLeBone());
       $attributes = array('appreciatedAs' => 'Steak'); 
       TBone::create($attributes);
    }

}
```

**Output when running the Test Case:**

```
saving
creating
```

So I am just wondering why the saving event is fired before the creating event?
Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug or feature, but you are right, according to the code, **create** calls **save**:

```
public static function create(array $attributes)
{
    $model = new static($attributes);

    $model->save();

    return $model;
}
```

And **save** fire the event:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    $query = $this->newQueryWithDeleted();

    // If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return
    // false, indicating that the save failed. This gives an opportunities to
    // listeners to cancel save operations if validations fail or whatever.
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

            ....
```

Before performing **insert** (create):

```
    else
    {
        $saved = $this->performInsert($query);
    }
```

Which fires the **creating** event

```
if ($this->fireModelEvent('creating') === false) return false;
```

Comment: Yeah it's more like a terminology clusterf***. I assumed. create means to create something in memory. save means to insert something into the database. Whereas laravel seems to use the term create as "insert". But then the "update" makes no sense.

Now I have to put in logic into my saving event handler to detrmine if an object already has been persisted, which I thought would have been unnecessary, because I have a creating event...

So yeah no bug just a way of intepretation...